# Where does form of posterior mean and covariance in gaussian process come from?

Tags: conditional-probability, gaussian-process, posterior

Let $f$ be $GP(0, k)$. Given set of observations $\{(x_i, y_i)\}_{i=1}^n, \; y_i = f(x_i) + \varepsilon_i$, где $\varepsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ posterior is written as
$$f_* \mid y \sim N(\boldsymbol{m}_{* \mid n}, \mathbf{K}_{*, * \mid n}),$$ where
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\boldsymbol{m}_{* \mid n} &=\mathbf{K}_{*, n}\left(\mathbf{K}_{n, n}+\sigma^{2} \mathbf{I}\right)^{-1} \boldsymbol{y} \\
\mathbf{K}_{*, * \mid n} &=\mathbf{K}_{*, *}-\mathbf{K}_{*, n}\left(\mathbf{K}_{n, n}+\sigma^{2} \mathbf{I}\right)^{-1} \mathbf{K}_{n, *}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Where do these formulas come from? How are they derived? Everywhere I saw them such form is just used without derivation .

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post this as a comment but I do not have enough reputation. I found this write up to be helpful:
http://ntur.lib.ntu.edu.tw/bitstream/246246/20060927122912664791/1/gpr.pdf